# C# Displaying data when selecting row in datagridview

Tags: c#

Apologies in advance if this question has been answered elsewhere (haven't found the answer after a few hours of searching).

Anyways, my code works, I've tested it using a button.
Selecting the row then clicking the button and it displays the correct data.

But I want it to display the data when I select row , instead of selecting a row then pressing a button.

My code:

```
private void dgvRecipes_CellContentClick(object sender, 
                                         DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

  if (dgvRecipes.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
  {
     int selectedRecipe = 
         int.Parse(dgvRecipes.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

     lblRecipe.Text = dgvRecipes.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

     string selectStr = "SELECT IngredDesc, IngredAmt, IngredComment " +
            "FROM Ingredient, RecipeIngredients 
             WHERE RecipeIngredients.RecipeNo = " + selectedRecipe +
             " AND Ingredient.IngredID = RecipeIngredients.IngredID ";


     dbCmd = new SqlCommand(selectStr, dbConn);
     dbAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(dbCmd);
     dbAdapter.Fill(ds, "RecipeIngredients");
     dgvIngredients.DataSource = ds.Tables["RecipeIngredients"];

     selectStr = "SELECT InstructionNo, Instructions FROM RecipeInstructions "
                + "WHERE RecipeInstructions.RecipeNo = " + selectedRecipe;


     dbCmd = new SqlCommand(selectStr, dbConn);
     dbAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(dbCmd);
     dbAdapter.Fill(ds, "RecipeInstructions");
     dgvInstructions.DataSource = ds.Tables["RecipeInstructions"];

  }

}
```

Again, apologies if I haven't phrased my question correctly and set out the code badly.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a [Selection Change event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  of Datagridview:

```
private void DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ......
}
```

To explain `TaW` usefull comment you will have to go in DatagridView's `properties` (from VS desgin) select the `Events` tab and Double click on the `SelectionChange` Event

Comment: I tried this and it didnt help. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: This should work; have you actually __hooked up__ the event or just added the code??

Comment: Thanks!, using the Events tab to change it worked.

I was just trying to change the code.

Answer (score 0):

You normally do this by a binding, so the textboxes display the same values without any extra code behind. 
But: you can also change the property called "selectionmode" of a datagrid; you should set in to selectRow. Then you can find the appropriate event and move the code you have under your button to that event

Answer (score 0):

Use [SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event of `DataGridView`.

SelectionChanged event occurs whenever cells are **selected** or the selection is **canceled**, whether **programmatically** or by **user action**.

Comment: second mention of SelectionChanged, maybe im missing something, because it hasnt changed anything .

it should be something like this right : 
private void dgvRecipes_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ code here }